# Save one part of a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files

I use a Rancid server to save information about Cisco switches on a network. I would like to write a Python 3 script to extract the configuration part of the data to a text file. I have gotten this to work but I have a file which has the configuration in it twice and I only want the first config.

This is what I have done:

```
import sys

flag = False

start = ('version', 'config-register')
end = ('@\n', 'monitor 6\n', 'end\n')

with open(sys.arbv[1], "r") as file:
         for line in file:

                   if line.startswith(start):
                           file = True;

                   if flag:
                           sys.stdout.write(line)

                   if line.endswith(end):
                           flag = False
```

The file which has the config it twice uses the `'version'` for the start and `'@\n'` for the end.  I have tried to use a `break` but I still get both of the config.

Example of file:
    !VTP: VTP Domain Name                 : 
    !VTP: VTP Pruning Mode                : Disabled (Operationally Disabled)
    !VTP: VTP V2 Mode                     : Disabled
    !VTP: VTP Traps Generation            : Disabled
    !VTP: MD5 Digest                      : 0x05 0xBB 0x45 0x03 0x57 0xBE      0xBA      0x57
    !VTP: VTP version running             : 1
    !
    !DEBUG: Debug level is set to Minor(1) 
    !DEBUG:  default for new sessions logging level: 3
    !
    !CORES: Module  Instance  Process-name     PID       Date(Year-Month-Day Time)
    !CORES: ------  --------  ---------------  --------  -------------------------
    !
    !PROC_LOGS: Process          PID     Normal-exit  Stack  Core   Log-create-time
    !PROC_LOGS: ---------------  ------  -----------  -----  -----  ---------------
    !

```
version 5.2(1)N1(4)
logging level feature-mgr 0
hostname 

no feature telnet
feature tacacs+
cfs eth distribute
feature udld
feature interface-vlan
feature lacp
feature vpc
feature lldp
feature vtp
feature fex

username (removed)

**** content removed ****

Interface Section


clock timezone CTD -6 0
line console
  exec-timeout 5
line vty
  session-limit 5
  session-limit 5
  exec-timeout 5
  access-class 3 in
boot kickstart 
boot system 
ip route 
no ip source-route


@


1.75
log
@updates
@
text
```

Comment: add the actual content, start and end make no sense, how could the section start with two different strings and end with three different strings?

Comment: I have three different types of switches, two files have the string 'config-register' while the third file has the 'version' string.  And each file has a separate string where the config ends.  The start variable is where I what the program to start coping and to stop at the end variable.

Comment: If you provide a sample it will be a lot easier to help you

Comment: OK I had to delete some info but here is an example if the file:

Comment: *** Start of File****version 5.2(1)N1(4)
logging level feature-mgr 0
hostname 

no feature telnet
feature tacacs+
cfs eth distribute
feature udld
feature interface-vlan
feature lacp
feature vpc
feature lldp
feature vtp
feature fex

username (removed)

Comment: Interface Section


clock timezone CTD -6 0
line console
  exec-timeout 5
line vty
  session-limit 5
  session-limit 5
  exec-timeout 5
  access-class 3 in
boot kickstart 
boot system 
ip route 
no ip source-route


@
***  End of File***

Comment: @Kobra Please edit your question and put the file content there, not in the comments!

Comment: Roland I have tried to do this but I can not get the site to accepted my formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ordering of version and config-register matter here. So you may be better off just iterating through the file twice. This way you can split up your sections of the file you need to find as groups. Once to find the values of version and once to find config-register.

```
import sys

flag = False

VERSION_NAME = r'version'

CONFIG_NAME = r'config-register'

end = ('@\n', 'monitor 6\n', 'end\n')

FILE_NAME = sys.argv[1]


# find the config-register
with open(FILE_NAME, "r") as file:
    start = CONFIG_NAME
    config_found = False

    for line in file:
        if line.startswith(start) and not config_found:
            flag = True                   # correction

        if flag:
            sys.stdout.write(line)
        if flag and line.endswith(end):
            print("Found Break")
            break                          # correction

        if line.startswith(start):
            config_found = True


# find the version
with open(FILE_NAME, "r") as file:
    start = VERSION_NAME
    config_found = False

    for line in file:
        if line.startswith(start) and not config_found:
            flag = True

        if flag:
            sys.stdout.write(line)

        if flag and line.endswith(end):
            print("Found Break")
            break

        if line.startswith(start):
            config_found = True
```

Then you would loop again and only search for the config-version and the "end" for that. This is not the most performance focused, but since you are not processing the whole file, hopefully this will meet your needs.